A non-null variable results me to NullReferenceException [Unity]
I've been on Unity for a very long time, yet I've come across the most common error.
I made a script to create a ship components store from a list of ScriptableObjects.
Here's the ScriptableObjects:
public class ShipComponent : ScriptableObject
{
    public int shipID;
    public string shipName;
    [TextArea] public string shipDescription;
    public ShipComponentType ComponentType;
    public float Mass;
    public float Friction;
    public float Thrust;
    public float Friction2AngularFrictionCoef;
    public float Thrust2AngularThrustCoef;
    public bool IsQuantum;
    public Sprite previewSprite;
}

public class DatabaseComponents : ScriptableObject
{
    public int databaseID;
    public string databaseName;

    public List<Guild> databaseGuilds;
}

public class Guild : ScriptableObject
{
    public int guildID;
    public string guildName;
    public List<GameObject> guildComponents;
}

Here is the entire code where my problem is :
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShipCreatorDEBUG : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Component Shop")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform shopPanel;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject guildNamePrefab;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject rowPrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private DatabaseComponents database;

    private Dictionary<Guild, List<ShipComponent>> guildToListComponents;

    private void Start()
    {
        guildToListComponents = GenerateShipComponentDictionary(database);
        GenerateShop();
    }

    // Shop
    void GenerateShop()
    {
        foreach (Transform trans in shopPanel)
        {
            Destroy(trans.gameObject);
        }

        foreach (var entry in guildToListComponents)
        {
            Guild guild = entry.Key;
            List<ShipComponent> shipComponents = entry.Value;

            if (shipComponents == null || shipComponents.Count == 0) continue;

            GameObject rowName = Instantiate(guildNamePrefab, shopPanel);
            TMP_Text tmp = rowName.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>();
            tmp.text = guild.guildName;

            int count = shipComponents.Count;
            int rowAmount = Mathf.CeilToInt(count / 3f);

            for (int i = 0; i < rowAmount; i++)
            {
                GameObject rowComponents = Instantiate(guildNamePrefab, shopPanel);

                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    int currentIndex = i * 3 + j;
                    if (currentIndex >= count) break;

                    Transform buttonTransform = rowComponents.transform.GetChild(j);
                    Button btn = buttonTransform.GetComponent<Button>();

                    ShipComponent sc = shipComponents[currentIndex]; // NullReferenceException here

                    btn.onClick.AddListener(() => SelectComponentInfo(sc));

                    Image image = buttonTransform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
                    image.sprite = sc.previewSprite;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void SelectComponentInfo(ShipComponent shipComponent)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    public Dictionary<Guild, List<ShipComponent>> GenerateShipComponentDictionary(DatabaseComponents database)
    {
        Dictionary<Guild, List<ShipComponent>> guildComponentsDictionary = new Dictionary<Guild, List<ShipComponent>>();

        foreach (Guild guild in database.databaseGuilds)
        {
            List<ShipComponent> shipComponentsList = new List<ShipComponent>();

            foreach (GameObject componentPrefab in guild.guildComponents)
            {
                ShipComponentObject shipComponentObject = componentPrefab.GetComponent<ShipComponentObject>();

                if (shipComponentObject != null)
                {
                    shipComponentsList.Add(shipComponentObject.shipComponent);
                }
            }

            guildComponentsDictionary[guild] = shipComponentsList;
        }

        return guildComponentsDictionary;
    }
}

Here are the log results :
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ShipCreatorDEBUG.GenerateShop () (at Assets/Assets/Scripts/TestS/ShipCreatorDEBUG.cs:57)
ShipCreatorDEBUG.Start () (at Assets/Assets/Scripts/TestS/ShipCreatorDEBUG.cs:20)

The only thing can be null is the shipComponents list, but it has 2 elements on it. It might be useless to send it because of this line :
if (shipComponents == null || shipComponents.Count == 0) continue;

Unless the problem is present but I don't see it, as you can see, the values are non-null but I still get a NullReferenceException error.
Any idea where this problem might be coming from? The function is executed in runtime.
(reasking the question because it seems they don't understand this is NOT a duplicate of the common NullReferenceException question)

You would need to articulate why this isn't a duplicate to the "What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?" question. Stating that it's not isn't enough.

I guess GameObject rowComponents = Instantiate(guildNamePrefab, shopPanel); should be GameObject rowComponents = Instantiate(rowPrefab, shopPanel);

I can't reproduce the problem because the question does not include steps on how to create the prefab(s) necessary to reproduce the issue. See [mre].
